Encrypting columns in Databricks using Python while retaining original datatype
I'm working on a data security project in Databricks using Python, and I need to encrypt certain columns in a DataFrame while ensuring that the encrypted columns retain their original datatype. I've followed below article, but struggling to find a solution that preserves the datatype integrity post-encryption.
https://medium.com/@datamadness/column-encryption-and-decryption-in-databricks-baf9ada3a7cf

can't you use a metadata.json file to register the column names and their datatype.

hi @ practicalGuy are you azure databricks

Hello @user238607 can you please elaborate, I'm not sure what you mean by metadata.json

Hello @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes, I need to achieve this in Azure databricks

List the dataframe columns which you want to encrypt and also note down the datatypes of those columns. Then you can stuff that information into a metadata.json which will accompany your encrypted file. During decryption time, descrypt the columns normally and then cast the columns to appropriate datatype from the metadata.json file.

This doesn't work @user238607, I can't simply cast, check this image https://i.sstatic.net/EEUG3.png temp is integer, after using aes_encrypt it is a string, If I cast string to int in this case, it gives me Null. I followed the encryption code in above medium article.

I have tried the approach below:
From a list of tuples, I defined a custom UDF (User Defined Function) to encrypt a column's values using XOR encryption. Then, I applied this UDF to create a new column in the DataFrame.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

data = [("Alice", 34), ("Bob", 45), ("Charlie", 28)]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), False),
    StructField("age", IntegerType(), False)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

def xor_encrypt(value):
    key = 42  # Encryption key
    return "".join(chr(ord(char) ^ key) for char in value)

encrypt_udf = udf(xor_encrypt, StringType())
encrypted_df = df.withColumn("encrypted_age", encrypt_udf(col("age").cast("string")))
encrypted_df.display()
encrypted_df.printSchema()

# Results:
# name  age encrypted_age
# Alice 34  
# Bob   45  
# Charlie   28  

# root
# |-- name: string (nullable = false)
# |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
# |-- encrypted_age: string (nullable = true)

In the code above, I defined a UDF named xor_encrypt that takes a string value and XOR encrypts it using a predefined key. It converts the input string to a list of characters, XOR encrypts each character with the key, and then joins the encrypted characters back into a string. I registered the UDF xor_encrypt with the DataFrame df using the withColumn method. I cast the "age" column to StringType before applying the UDF to ensure compatibility.
